# Unofficial Sitecore 8 Training Webinar Series – Session 5

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time: November 16th, 2016 8:00 PM PT (03:00 UTC Nov 18th) – 9:00 PM PT (04:00 UTC Nov 19th)

Click here for more information: https://goo.gl/zIJmpU

1. Introduction to Sitecore PowerShell Extensions
2. Out of the Box
3. Meat & Potatoes
4. Remoting

Registration Link: https://goo.gl/OBvPrg

Comment: Event added to the board

Comment: The disposition and accommodation for these types of posts/activities is currently under consideration and will be resolved in the upcoming weeks.

Comment: This has now been resolved.